# How to create a relationship between 2 classes using parse.com?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Parse.com and JavaScript SDK.

I have a class called "FriendRequest" which I want to create a relationship with a child class called "myBadges"

The myBadges class stores multiple uploads by different users and I want to link it back to the FriendRequest class so that when I user uploads something, all of these can be accessed via the FriendRequest class using a field name "Item".

At the moment the code looks like this, which is saving the users upload to the "myBadges" class. But how do I add the relationship?

Do I just add this under the success function?

I have created the relationship column "BADGE" in the data browser already

```
  var relation = user.relation("FriendRequest");
  relation.add(BADGE);
```

EXISTING CODE

```
Parse.initialize("xxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxx");
                var MyBadges = Parse.Object.extend("myBadges");

                var userbadges = new MyBadges();
                var user = Parse.User.current();

                    $(document).ready(function () {

                    $("#send").click(function () {

                        var badgeselected = $('#badgeselect .go').attr("src");
                        userbadges.set("BadgeName", badgeselected);
                        userbadges.set("fromUser", user);
                        userbadges.set("BadgeStatus", "BadgeConnected");



                        userbadges.save(null, {
                            success: function (results) {
                        // The object was saved successfully.
                        console.log(user);

                        //location.reload();
                    },
```

---

![enter image description here][1] 
![enter image description here][3]

Answer (score 0):

you could try reading the Rest API on 'roles'  & 'creating roles'

it explains how to add a relation , ie an array of children objs from a diff class

youre using JS so here is some code that also adds an array of children (type=_User):

```
  success: function(parent) {
      _role = parent;
      qu.get(userId, {
        success: function(child) {
            //setters on _role
            _role.getChildren().add(user);
            _role.save();
            response.success(_role.toJSON());
        },
        error: function(object, error) {
            console.log('got role, failed on get user');
        }
      });     
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, this could be something I consider for the future. For now I was wondering if this solution would meet my needs https://parse.com/questions/pointers-user-with-javascript I guess I could create the pointer to the class I want?